# Flyway configuration without datasource

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

Try to setup `Flyway v6.0.8` with `Spring Boot v2.2.1.RELEASE` in `application.yaml` file:

```
spring:

  # CockroachDB connection
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/defaultdb
    username: test_user
    password: qwerty
    schema: some_schema

  flyway:
    # Doesn't support r2dbc driver, and don't think it's really necessary just for database structuring(will be no actual data migrations) 
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/defaultdb 
    # schemas: some_schema
    user: test_user
    password: qwerty
```

I want to configure Flyway just using `spring.flyway.url/user/password` without defining any `spring.datasource` in addition. As I understand that's possible to do based on [this merged PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/960c03dee5e56e5371ed5f297118f090d7248ba7) but I still have faced with the following exception regarding not defined datasource:

```
Caused by: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'flyway' parameter 1; nested exception org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseType
```

What I do wrong?

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '6.1.1'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
}

ext {
    r2dbcPostgresqlVersion = '0.8.0.RELEASE'
    postgresqlVersion = '42.2.9'
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    implementation('org.flywaydb:flyway-core')

    implementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:${r2dbcPostgresqlVersion}")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlVersion}")

    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    annotationProcessor('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-bom-r2dbc:0.1.0.M3")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have code of your own that is enabling `DataSourceProperties`? It should have backed off if `EmbeddedDatabaseType` isn’t on the classpath.

Comment: Checked one more time, nothing configured that might have references to DataSourceProperties.

Comment: Updated question description adding one more message in exception log.

Comment: if you look in this merge https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/880721557bf92e4b230f5f2cfff71e23bbfbfcc9 you will see that you require a datasource. They just changed the logic as to where the datasource is fetched from.

Comment: @ViktorV. Can you create a minimal and complete example and share it somewhere please?

Comment: Will try to do that today. SOme extra information based on the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup. If spring.flyway.url or spring.flyway.user is defined then flyway will try to create its own datasource otherwise spring.datasource will look at.